# Was there any currency backed by other metals than gold, silver or copper?

Tags: money, nonexpert, economic-history

Was any other metal than gold, silver or copper ever in history used to back a currency?

Comment: Not quite sure if you only mean paper currency backed by metals or actual metal coins as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Spartan iron coins](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1086107?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

Roman bronze coins: [Aes Grave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aes_grave)

Chinese bronze coins: [Ban liang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Chinese_coinage#Ban_Liang_coins) (one type was bronze, not all)

A non-metal "currency" backed by various industrial metals: the cryptocurrency [Tiberius coin](http://www.cda.org.uk/2019/10/tiberius-cryptocurrency-backed-by-metals/).